# In Selenium which type of "list" the method FindElement stores the value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium we are used the syntax :
List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));

In this syntax we are store many values in object reference "rows".

**But my question is** in this syntax which type of list we are using to store a values??

Comment: its just List. Not array or linked list

Comment: You could just do `System.out.println(rows.getClass())`, it will always return the *true* type, even if someone *lowered the view* to it. For example `Object o = "test"; System.out.println(o.getClass());` outputs `class java.lang.String` and not `Object` or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you mention:

```
List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
```

Java basically creates a `List` which can hold several items of type `Object` which is `raw type` but would complain and would provide a suggestion to change it to a `List` of `generic type`.

For example if you place the following code of a `raw List` in IDE and mouse hover the `raw List` you will observe `Java Compiler` complaining:

[image]

Best practices suggest that, we should always create a generic `List` as per the type of items. An ideal way to create a `List` to store `WebElements` which is returned by `driver.findElements(By.xpath("my_xpath"))` would be as follows:

```
List<WebElement> dd_menu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//li/a"));
```

Now if you mouse hover the method `findElements()` you will observe `findElements()` method always returns `List<WebElement>`.

[image]

In this case Java compiler don't have any complain about your code.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @debanjanB..If i am correct,you are saying Its a only list which can store multiple value in it.

Comment: @PiyushGarg All types of `List` can store multiple values. A `List` can also be a type of `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector` or `Stack`. To keep my Answer simple, short & sweet, as an example I took up `findElements()`used in Selenium. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replaying,now i am getting a point what are you saying

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriver` is an **interface** and it demands implementations to return a `List` but it does not specifiy which specific list, this is up to the implementations. And there are several implementations.

Note that a `List` is just an **interface**, there are also multiple implementations like `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and others. You can see a full list of implementing classes (of the standard API) in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

---

My current **Geckodriver** (Firefox family) and **Chromedriver** (Chrome family) return a [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) when used with `By.tagName` for example.

However, as said, other implementations can return other `List` objects and there is no guarantee that gecko- and chromedriver will also always return a `LinkedList` in the future, they could change that as the interface only require a `List`.

---

Note that you can always check the current type of an object by using the `Object#getClass` method.

```
List rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
System.out.println(rows.getClass());
```

---

Also note that in case of Selenium you can just look up the implementation, it is open source: [Selenium at GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium).

We see that for example `ChromeDriver` and `FirefoxDriver` inherit from [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java). Its `findElements` method delegates the task to the [By](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java) object which is an abstract class, so we need to head over to specific implementations of `By` and so on.

In the end, with **XPath**, we land at the class [BaseFinder](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/lift/find/BaseFinder.java) which is used for finding the matches. This class finally uses `ArrayList`.

Comment: @zubuza i am aggree with your point but now when I see in chrome,its displaying -----------class java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Yeah, see my edit. If it is still unclear then please call back :)